# Finding eachother on a sphere

Tags: probability, geometry, spheres

Imagine you and your friend are on a huge sphere like the moon (radius **r**). You start at two oposite sides of the sphere and you move with a constant speed (**v**) yet in a completely random way (not the best example, but somehow like molecules). How long does it take until you and your friend meet eachother (the distance between you becomes less than **d**? And what about this question in just 2 dimensions (2 points moving on a circle)?

Interesting to know would also be a function that shows the probability of both friends having met eachother after a certain amount of time has passed. ( p(t) = ...)

I know that my question is similar to this problem: "[Fastest way to meet, without communication, on a sphere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214022/fastest-way-to-meet-without-communication-on-a-sphere)" but I couldn't find the answer to my question in the comments.

Comment: Look at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214022/fastest-way-to-meet-without-communication-on-a-sphere/1218124#1218124

Comment: It is a similar but yet different question since it's not about moving randomly but rather about finding the most efficient solution. And the case of both players moving randomly isn't covered.

Comment: What does movement with constant speed in a random direction mean? Can we imagine straight line (resp. geodetic) movement with a new direction chosen at random after every interval $\Delta t$, and then use the limit $\Delta t\to 0$?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant